# "We had enough firewood to keep us warm" and "We had enough firewood to keep ourselves warm" correct one?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

- ***"We had enough firewood to keep us warm"*** *(I found this example in a book)*
- ***"We had enough firewood to keep ourselves warm"*** *(whereas this is the main question if this is correct)*

-which one is correct and why?
-And if both are correct, what's the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: Both are correct. The first focuses on the firewood providing heat to keep us warm; the second on our use of it for that purpose (warming ourselves).

Answer (score 1):

They are equally idiomatic in my view. Perhaps by using "ourselves" it tends to place the emphasis on the people themselves, as opposed to the house generally.